# How is the start of repeating decimals defined?

Tags: terminology

Today I tried to find the period length of the repeating decimals of [`8/86`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8%2F86) by asking WolframAlpha (yes a somewhat stupid question because it's the same as `1/43`).

[image]

Here I found the repeating decimals being `930232558139534883720`; isn't it the same as `093023255813953488372`? If I try `1/11` it's `90`, again starting with a non-zero digit.

**Is this *just a convention* or is there *a deeper truth*?** (sorry for this maybe trivial question)

Comment: I think it's just a choice they made when they wrote WolframAlpha.

Comment: @GerryMyerson so you'd say that it's only a convention of some sort?

Comment: Yes, but specifically a convention of WolframAlpha, rather than a common convention of Mathematics. Anyway, I never heard of it before.

Comment: How would you describe the relation between the repeating decimals of `1/111` and `10/111`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you want to be precise you say that there is a choice of preperiod such that $1/111$ and $10/111$ have the same period. Usually, you simply say that the two numbers have the same period (implying an appropriate choice for the preperiod).

Comment: @A.P. yes maybe something like that, but of course this becomes pointless for, say, `1000/111`... and here the convention of WA seems a bit "idiotic" - [have a look...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1000%2F111)

Comment: Note that only digits in the fractional part of a number are usually considered part of the period (see the comment to my answer). Why do you say that the WA convention seems idiotic?

Comment: @A.P. *`only digits in the fractional part`* thanks for clarifying. I wrote *a bit* before the harsh word, but...

Comment: It would be harsh to call this a bug; but it's hard to believe that they did this deliberately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it is just a convention. We say that a real number $\alpha$, say in the interval $(0,1)$, is *ultimately periodic* (in base $10$) if there are two finite sequences of digits (usually called *words*) $U = d_1d_2\dotsc d_n$ and $V = d_{n+1}d_{n+2}\dotsc d_{n+m}$ such that $\alpha = 0.UV^{\omega}$ in decimal notation, where $V^{\omega}$ stands for the concatenation of $V$ with itself countably many times. The words $U$ and $V$ are called the $preperiod$ and $period$ of $\alpha$, respectively.

As you noticed, if a number is ultimately periodic there are *infinitely many* choices for $U$ and $V$, and we are free to choose the one that best fits our purposes at a given time. This usually means a representation where the lengths of both $U$ and $V$ are minimal.

I have no clue why Wolfram Alpha gives that particular representation, though. A possible explanation is that internally it represents the period as an integer, so it would lose any leading zeros unless they were included in the preperiod.

Comment: Note that we can easily extend this definition to any real number by saying that $\alpha$ is ultimately periodic if and only if its mantissa (fractional part) is. This is sensible because the integer part of $\alpha$ can be represented with finitely many digits.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a preferred form which the WA computational engine wants to keep its numbers in.
An internal normalization.

This way you have a decimal representation with maximal fixed width $f$
$$
x = 
(d_m\cdots d_0.\underbrace{d_{-1}\cdots d_{-f}}_f\underbrace{\overline{d_{-(f+1)}\cdots d_{-(f+p)}}}_p)_{10} \\
$$
and the periodical part will show up in calculations as
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(d_{-(f+1)}\cdots d_{-(f+p)})_{10}}{10^{f+kp}}
&=
\frac{(d_{-(f+1)}\cdots d_{-(f+p)})_{10}}{10^f} 
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{10^p}\right)^k
\\
&=
\frac{(d_{-(f+1)}\cdots d_{-(f+p)})_{10}}{10^f}
\left(\frac{1}{1-1/10^p} - 1\right)
\\
&=
\frac{(d_{-(f+1)}\cdots d_{-(f+p)})_{10}}{10^f(10^p-1)}
\end{align}
It might be convenient to have the first digit of the periodical part $d_{-f+1}$ non-zero.